# How can I increase the vertical size of a pre defined transformer core?

Tags: circuitikz, size

How can I increase the vertical size of a pre defined transformer core?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}                           % for flowcharts
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes.arrows,decorations.pathmorphing, matrix,chains,scopes,positioning,fit,shapes.gates.logic.US, shapes.gates.logic.IEC, calc, decorations.markings,arrows.meta,bending}
\usepackage{textcomp} % avoid the warning from gensymbol's package

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \draw (0,0)
    to[short,o-] (1,0) 
    to[R] (2.5,0)
    to[L] (4,0)
    to[short,-*] (5.5,0)
    -- (7,0)
    (8,0) node[transformer core] (T) {} (T.B1) -- (9.5,0)
    to[L] (11,0)
    to[R] (12.5,0)
    to [short,-o] (13.5,0)
    (5.5,0) -- (5.5,-0.4)
    -- (5.9, -0.4)
    to[L] (5.9,-1.9)
    -- (5.5,-1.9)
    -- (5.5,-2.3);  

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is something like `node[transformer core,yscale=2] (T) {} (T.B1)` or `node[transformer core,yscale=2,transform shape]` what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'd like to joint the terminal of the opened vertical inductor to the opened T.A2 terminal with a straigt line. @gonzalo Medina that was the perfect answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like

```
node[transformer core,yscale=2] (T)
```

or

```
node[transformer core,yscale=2,transform shape] (T)
```

However, instead of scaling the transformer, I'd suggest you another approach:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}                           % for flowcharts
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes.arrows,decorations.pathmorphing, matrix,chains,scopes,positioning,fit,shapes.gates.logic.US, shapes.gates.logic.IEC, calc, decorations.markings,arrows.meta,bending}
\usepackage{textcomp} % avoid the warning from gensymbol's package

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
    \draw (0,0)
    to[short,o-] (1,0) 
    to[R] (2.5,0)
    to[L] (4,0)
    to[short,-*] (5.5,0)
    -- (7,0)
    (8,0) node[transformer core] (T) {} (T.B1) -- (9.5,0)
    to[L] (11,0)
    to[R] (12.5,0)
    to [short,-o] (13.5,0)
  (5.5,0) |- 
  ([shift={(10pt,-10pt)}]5.5,0) 
   to[L]
  ([shift={(10pt,10pt)}]5.5,0|-T.A2) -|
  (5.5,0|-T.A2) -- 
  (T.A2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]